# How to loop through a directory in perl

Tags: perl, loops

I have a directory `dir1` containing several hundreds of files, which are to be iteratively processed by a speech program called HRest. The program is supposed to take each file one by one, process it and put it in a new directory (as `dir2` for first iteration) to be used in next iteration. My problem is that i don't know if the way I've employed to loop through the files in `dir1`, and also the way I am running the script `(trainhmms.pl dir1 1)` is correct.

If the files in dir1 are L1, L2, L3, ..., L500, I want `HRest` to be executed as

```
HRest -T 1 -I timedlabels_train.mlf -t -i 20 -l dir1/L1 -M dir2 -S train.scp
```

for the first file, and as

```
HRest -T 1 -I timedlabels_train.mlf -t -i 20 -l dir1/L2 -M dir2 -S train.scp
```

for the next file, and so on for all files. Then in next call of the script, I want it to be changed to

```
HRest -T 1 -I timedlabels_train.mlf -t -i 20 -l dir2/L1 -M dir3 -S train.scp
```

for the first file, and so on..

Here is the script for the first iteration:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Slurp;

# Usage: trainhmms.pl dir1 1
# dir1:  Folder containing models after being initialised by HInit (L1,L2,..,L512)

$file = $ARGV[0];
$iter = $ARGV[1];


my @files = read_dir '/Users/negarolfati/Documents/Detection_rerun/AF_TIMIT/1_state//trainHMMs/dir1';

for my $file ( @files ) {


    $iter2 = $iter+1;
    $cmd = "HRest -T 1 -I timedlabels_train.mlf -t -i 20 -l '$dir[$iter]/$file' -M '$dir[$iter2]' -S train.scp ";

    system("$cmd");

}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by `$dir[$iter]` and `$dir[$iter2]`. They access an array called `@dir` which doesn't exist.

Comment: by $dir[$iter], I want to access to the folder dir1 during the first iteration, process all files in that folder, and then put store the processed files in dir2.

Comment: But what *are* those directories?

Comment: If the files in dir1 are L1, L2, L3, ..., L500, I want the HRest to be executed as:  HRest -T 1 -I timedlabels_train.mlf -t -i 20 -l dir1/L1' -M dir2 -S train.scp for the first file, and as HRest -T 1 -I timedlabels_train.mlf -t -i 20 -l dir1/L2 -M dir2 -S  for the next file, and so on for all files. then in next call of the script, I want it to be changed to   HRest -T 1 -I timedlabels_train.mlf -t -i 20 -l dir2/L1' -M dir3 -S train.scp for the first file, and so on..

Comment: I hope its clear now

Comment: Im calling the script iteratively from a shell script, as: for i in {1..4};do, trainhmms.pl dir$i $i  , done ,  ....   at each iteration, it is supposed to take all files from dir$i, process them and put them in a new directory dir(($i+1))

Comment: I think it would be better to write both loops in Perl, rather than one in bash and the other in Perl. Anyway, I have written something that I think should help. Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You can't just use `readdir` on a directory string. You have to `opendir` the string, then `readdir` from the directory handle that you get, and finally `closedir` the handle.</strike>

You must also remember that `readdir` returns directory names as well as file names, <strike>and the pseudo-directories `.` and `..` too</strike>. To filter out just the files, you can use the `-f` test operator. And it is usually most convenient to `chdir` to the directory you are reading so that you don't have to append the path to each file name that `readdir` returns before you do the test.

I don't know what `HRest` is, but if your command line must be executed from a specific working directory (perhaps to acccess `timedlabels_train.mlf` and `train.scp`) then please say so. I will have to remove the `chdir` statement.

Something like this should get you going. I have used `autodie`, which does automatic checks on file system operations. It saves having to check `chdir` and `opendir` explicitly each time with `or die $!`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use File::Spec::Functions 'catdir';

my ($file, $iter) = @ARGV;

my $root = '/Users/negarolfati/Documents/Detection_rerun/AF_TIMIT/1_state/trainHMMs';
my $dir1 = catdir $root, 'dir'.$iter;
my $dir2 = catdir $root, 'dir'.($iter+1);

chdir $dir1;

opendir my ($dh), '.';
my @files = grep -f, readdir $dh;
closedir $dh;

for my $file ( @files ) {

    my $cmd = "HRest -T 1 -I timedlabels_train.mlf -t -i 20 -l '$dir1/$file' -M '$dir2' -S train.scp";

    system($cmd);
}
```

---

**Update**

Here is an alternative version that avoids `chdir` so that the current working directory remains unchanged.

I have added the secondary loop that was in your bash script. I have also added a `print` statement so that you can see each command before it is executed.

To allow the `system` call to go ahead, just delete or comment out the `next` statement.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use File::Spec::Functions qw/ catdir catfile /;

STDOUT->autoflush;

my $root = '/Users/negarolfati/Documents/Detection_rerun/AF_TIMIT/1_state/trainHMMs';

for my $iter (1 .. 4) {

  my $dir1 = catdir $root, 'dir'.$iter;
  my $dir2 = catdir $root, 'dir'.($iter+1);

  opendir my ($dh), $dir1;

  while (my $node = readdir $dh) {
    my $file = catfile($dir1, $node);
    next unless -f $file;

    my $cmd = "HRest -T 1 -I timedlabels_train.mlf -t -i 20 -l '$file' -M '$dir2' -S train.scp";
    print $cmd, "\n";
    next;               # Remove for full functionality

    system($cmd);
  }

  closedir $dh;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such an impressive answer Borodin! But when I try it, I get the following error: InitSource: Cannot open source file /Users/negarolfati/Documents/Detection_rerun/AF_TIMIT/1_state/trainHMMs/dir1//Users/negarolfati/Documents/Detection_rerun/AF_TIMIT/1_state/trainHMMs/dir1/L505     ....there the $root is repeated twice but i can not figure out where to change, could you kindly help me?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! Its working now, thank you so much for such a great help! :)

Comment: @Borodin, the question uses [`File::Slurp`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurp)'s [`read_dir`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurp#read_dir) which *does* operate on a string containing a directory name and *doesn't* return `.` or `..`.

Comment: @Jim Davis, so you mean the way I used read_dir is also correct?

Comment: Yep.  You still need to prefix the result with the directory name to get the full path, though

Comment: @JimDavis: Damn, you're quite right. Thanks for correcting me. I hate that module for so many reasons!

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
my @files = <$path/*>;
foreach my $filename ( reverse(@files) ) {
...
}
```